# How do I find and sort a directory by the longest file path?

Tags: osx, directory, filenames, sort

I'm on OS X, trying to connect Microsoft OneDrive, which has a hard path limit. I need to find the longest paths in a directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following command will give you the character count of every regular file (remove the `-type f` for all types of files including directories) underneath the directory you execute it in, and sort them so the longest ones are output last:

```
find . -type f -print|awk '{print length($0), $0}' | sort -n
```

It assumes file and directory names don't contain newline characters.

Comment: What if the longest path is due to a empty directory?

Comment: `find . -printf '%p\n' | awk '{ n = length($0); if (n > nmax) { nmax = n; longest=$0 }} END { if (nmax > 0) printf "%s\n", longest }'` will list all filesystem objects, and only print the longest one.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the longest path you want or the longest file name? Between `foo/bar/baz` and `foobar`, is it `foo/bar/baz` (longest path), or `foobar` (name longer than `baz`)?

With `zsh`:

```
path_length() REPLY=$#REPLY
name_length() REPLY=${#REPLY:t}

# longest name:
ls -ld -- **/*(DnO+name_length[1])

# longest path:
ls -ld -- **/*(DnO+path_length[1])
```

Note that it counts those lengths in number of characters, not bytes. You could change the locale to C to count in bytes, but then we don't know how the file names are encoded on the remote host and what counts to that *limit* you're referring to. For instance, € is encoded in one byte in iso8859-15, two in UTF-16 and three in UTF-8.